# uploading zip to GCP jupyterlab is superslow

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I was using the jupyterlab notebook instance at AI platform at GCP. You can access this by 1) entering GCP console, 2) search notebook instance and choose the entry with the subtitle of AI platform. 3) create one.

When I upload a zip to the jupyterlab, the speed is very very slow.

Don't know what to do. It is very frustrating when cost a day just to upload the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Davic at GCP 24/7 chat support is helpful. After checking a bunch of things such as network speed (http://speedtest.net)

I found the speed of uploading a single file is pretty fast. And the network is pretty good too. Since my dataset is available at Kaggle, I just thought why not download directly from kaggle.

So I used the following commands:

```
pip install kaggle
mv kaggle.json /home/jupyter/.kaggle. # download your kaggle.json from profile page, upload it to jupyterlab, and move this place
chmod 600 /home/jupyter/.kaggle
kaggle download datasets {username/dataset name}
```

It is done!! Just 5 seconds, I guess, the dataset is deployed!!